# AngularJS icon changes with a list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug, frontend

I'm working in AngularJS / Jade, and I need to change an icon when you click on something. Currently I have the following code:

```
a(onclick='return false', href='#general', data-toggle='tab') General 
  span.glyphicon(ng-class='isGeneralChanged(selected) ? "glyphicon-ok-circle" : "glyphicon-adjust"')
```

Then below that:

```
.form-group
   label Has the design entered?
   toggle-switch(model='selected.general_engineer_made_inspection', on-label='Yes', off-label='No')
```

So basically the problem I have is that here it's easy, it's either "yes" or "no" and that changes the icon, but the next tab is just a list of names that once you just click on one the icon in the tab should change. I'm not sure how I could solve this. `ng-click` event?

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean to hide,show,toggle elements. Angular makes this easy. (look up `ng-show`, `ng-hide`, `ng-switch`)

Also, I prefer to use `ng-class` this way:

```
i.fa.fw(ng-class="{true:'fa-lock', false:'fa-unlock'}[locked]")
```

The initial value is set in the controller:

```
$scope.locked = true;
```

Then, a button that toggles the boolean (and thus, the class) is added to the view. Note the `ng-click="locked=!locked"`

```
button(ng-click="locked=!locked" ng-switch="locked")
    span(ng-switch-when="true") Lock
    span(ng-switch-when="false") Unlock
```

We can also employ the boolean to hide or show whatever we'd like:

```
pre(ng-show="locked") Locked!
pre(ng-show="!locked) Unlocked!
```

Here's a Plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/0PDT2cpQGwFKsu8h1hdg?p=preview that covers all of the above (albeit, in HTML, not Jade). The demo uses [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/icon/unlock/).

Comment: Sorry couzzi, I may have been unclear on the problem. In tab1 I can change the icon with the toggle switch which is a button, the problem I have is, I have a list of names in the database that get rendered out in tab2, each has an id. I need to click on one of those names and once I click on a name it automatically goes to tab3. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Hey couzzi, I figured it out. I renamed the tabs and added a '.removeClass' and '.addclass' and then made them active depending on which tap you are going to next.